# Prevent user to stop a macro (Excel VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to prevent a user from stopping a macro during saving.
I have found the following code :

```
Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
```

It works if you hit the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key once, but if you hold the key a long time you  can stop the macro.

I tried `Application.EnableCancelKey = xlErrorHandler` as follow :

```
Application.EnableCancelKey = xlErrorHandler
On Error GoTo errHandler:

ActiveWorkbook.Save

exitHere:
  Exit Sub

errHandler:
  msgbox"something"
  Resume exitHere
```

Sometime it works perfectly, but sometimes if I hit the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key at the perfect moment and for a few seconds, I am able to stop the macro.

Do you know if there is a way to inactive <kbd>ESC</kbd> key for real?

Comment: Thank you to Ariful Haque for the help on how to edit a question.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this, but this is how I would start from your code:

```
On Error GoTo errHandler:
Application.EnableCancelKey = xlErrorHandler

ActiveWorkbook.Save

Application.EnableCancelKey = xlInterrupt

exitHere:
  Exit Sub


errHandler:
  If MsgBox("something", vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then
    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlInterrupt
    Exit Sub
  End If

  Resume
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
The errHandler works but sometime an error occurs during the first line of the errHandler (in that case If msgBox...). It looks like I need an error Handler of my error handler !!